# Selecting a dynamic range with variable values in a single column

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, range

I wish to perform a calculation on a dynamic range of cells in a single column based on a numeric range of 50 to 550. The data in the column starts close to 0 and ends over 900 in values, I need the range to select the cell with the closest value less than or equal to 50 as the start and the closest value greater than or equal to 550 as the end.

I need to find the median of the G column. The range of G column data used for this needs to match the E column range (between 50 and 550). I hope this makes sense!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please, show us what did you try by your own. Even if it did  not work as you need...

Comment: Here's my attempt so far: =MEDIAN(G8:G300(IF(E7:E300>=50,IF(E7:E300<=550,IF(E7:E300<>"",E7:E300)))))

I didn't explain in the original question, the median calculation needs to be done on the G column data using the range of rows found in E between the values of 50 and 550

Comment: OK. I will post an answer in some minutes...

Comment: Thank you! Here's a screen shot of the data sheet: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1e_Bbhc2TYSEMEFZeNu8ClUmJ2pxfK4pW/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Only now I could see your comment. Since you did not place any picture in your question and you did not say anything about the structure of the sheet to be analyzed, I posted a generic example, processing the column A:A. Anyhow, I do not understand too much from the screen shot you show us in the link. You do not say anything about the column to be processed and the one where the processing result to be returned. But, test my code as it is and then, if you are not able to implement it, **try clearly explaining what you want accomplishing**. But this is not a proper way to ask a question!

Comment: Thanks. Sorry for not being clear! here's a better view of the sheet: https://drive.google.com/file/d/13E5xk_rTOB3JTKqcjgHhelvE23i35f9-/view?usp=sharing

I'll try your code as soon as I can. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Now I only can see a better view of the same sheet. But, how do you imagine I can deduce which column should be processed, if you do not supply this piece of information? Then, you were asking about the range selection. How this selection to be handled by anything in the sheet picture from the link? But, did you try testing my code? Or you need a specific one to solve your not explained need?

Comment: I need the median of the G column. I explained that in my comment above. The range of G column data need to match the E column - your code does work to find the correct E column range. Thank you!

Comment: I suppose you mean that edited your question. But, even with the new piece of information, if the range to be processed is clear, where from to be extracted the two numbers to be searched for? Let us say, that a cell in G:G with be the minimum/maximum, but where from to be extracted the other necessary one? Anyhow, do you consider that my code answered your question or not?

Comment: The G column range needs to match the E column. The median value I need should come from the G column data.

Comment: You code does work on column E

Comment: I did try to explain this in my second comment. 

(Here's my attempt so far: =MEDIAN(G8:G300(IF(E7:E300>=50,IF(E7:E300<=550,IF(E7:E300<>"",E7:E300))))) I didn't explain in the original question, the median calculation needs to be done on the G column data using the range of rows found in E between the values of 50 and 550)

Comment: The code works on column E:E, is the single clear statement... Don't the function need two numbers to set the range between their positions? Where from the second such number to be extracted? All the time the should the function use 50 and 550? I thought that this are variables... And you did not answer my last question: "... **do you consider that my code answered your question, as it has been formulated, or not**? "

Comment: I'm very confused now! Your code did find the range in column E. It doesn't completely answer my question though! Thanks for trying!

Comment: All the time the should the function use 50 and 550? Yes.

Comment: What question? Can you copy here this unanswered question, please? But copied from the text you posted.

Comment: What do you need to do with the returned range?

Comment: Would you like to return the MEDIAN function result for the range defined by the function? I can do it if this is what you want. But using all the time the same interval (50 - 550), will not obtain the same range all the times and the same result for all G:G column?

Answer (score 0):

Please, try the next function. It assumes that in column A:A of the active sheet there are at least two numbers, starting from A2:

```
Function setRngCloseNr(rng As Range, smallNo As Double, bigNo As Double) As Range
 Dim startCell As Range, endCell As Range, nrStart As Long, nrEnd As Long
 
 If rng.cells.count < 3 Then MsgBox "No range to be processed was sent...": Exit Function
 
 nrStart = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(smallNo, rng, 1, True) 'the number closed to the smaller one
 Set startCell = rng.Find(what:=nrStart, After:=rng.cells(1.1), _
     SearchDirection:=xlNext, LookIn:=xlValues, MatchCase:=False) 'the cell containing the small No
     
 nrEnd = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(bigNo, rng, 1, True) 'the number closed to the larger one
 Set endCell = rng.Find(what:=nrEnd, After:=startCell, _
      SearchDirection:=xlNext, LookIn:=xlValues, MatchCase:=False) 'the cell containing the largest No
      
 If (Not startCell Is Nothing) Or (Not endCell Is Nothing) Then
    Set setRngCloseNr = rng.Parent.Range(startCell, endCell) ' the range to be returned
 End If
End Function
```

The above function should be called/used like in the following example:

```
Sub testSetRngClNr()
  Dim sh As Worksheet, rng As Range, lastRow As Long, rngF As Range
  Set sh = ActiveSheet
  lastRow = sh.Range("A" & rows.count).End(xlUp).row
  Set rng = sh.Range("A2:A" & lastRow)
  
  Set rngF = setRngCloseNr(rng, 50, 550)
  'check if the function returned a range:
  If rngF Is Nothing Then MsgBox "No range could be built!": Exit Sub
  rngF.Select               'select the returned range
  Debug.Print rngF.Address  'return the range address
End Sub
```

Please, send some feedback after testing it.